# React Material UI - Prevent re-rendering child component Tabs on Tab change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have a list of "tasks" I'd like to map where each task has its own set of tabs. In the TabPanel, there is a component TaskOrg which fetches stuff from the backend (api calls that's significant) and displays the data in a DataGrid. I have no problem isolating each tab, meaning I can click on a tab and it behaves separately from all other tabs.

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState({})

useEffect(() => {
    if (provincialTasks.length > 0) {
        let tabs = {}
        provincialTasks.forEach(task => {

            tabs[task.id] = false
        })

        setValue(tabs)
    }
}, [provincialTasks])

function TabPanel(props) {
    const {children, value, index, ...other} = props;

    return (
        <div
            role="tabpanel"
            hidden={value !== index}
            id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
            aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
            {...other}
        >
            {value === index && (
                <Box sx={{p: 3}}>
                    <Typography>{children}</Typography>
                </Box>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

...

return (
    {provincialSection.legalTasks?.map((provincialTask) => {
        return (
            <Tabs value={value[provincialTask.id]}>
                <Tab value={`org-tab-${provincialTask.id}`} {...a11yProps(`org-tab-${provincialTask.id}`)} />
            </Tabs>
        <TabPanel value={value[provincialTask.id]} index={`org-tab-${provincialTask.id}`}>
            <TaskOrg value={provincialTask.id} {...other} />
        </TabPanel>
    )
    }}

)
```

The problem is that every time something changes in the parent, everything gets re-rendered, including tabs, of course. But on re-render, the TaskOrg also resets and fetches again the data from the backend and it displays that same data. I know there is `useMemo` but that only works for a single component. In this case, the `provincialTasks` objects can vary between 10-20... that's a lot of calls.

I tried passing an `active` prop to the TaskOrg component to only fetch data if I'm in the right tab, but it still doesn't prevent the re-render of that set of tabs (if I switch between tab for the same task).

Is there a way to prevent re-rendering on a set of child components, namely TaskOrg components should the parent decide it changed its state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you shared I suspect that you have that function called `TabPanel` that returns a component within your main component. When you do that, every time the main component updates, it updates the function as well, re-rendering the `TabPanel`. You should declare that function outside the main component to prevent unwanted re-renders

Comment: I think I read something like that in a git. What do you mean outside the main component?

Comment: That's why you need to attach a reproducible example as the community says. But basically, when you declare a component within another, it may triggers unwanted behavior. The best you can do is abstract components to other files and pass the props accordingly

Comment: In this sandbox I made based on your code I pointed out what I'm trying to tell you https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-flower-cvflkl

Comment: I finally got it. Didn’t realize that throwing components their own file would solve this problem. Thank you.